# Issue selecting nodes in hierarchy

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using Scenebuilder to create a personal application which displays my classes, assignments, exams, etc. I have a scene containing a `MenuBar` item and a `TableView` item.

When I select a `Node` in the hierarchy `Panel`, the Inspector `Panel` does not see the selected `Item`. If I select a `Node` in the drag and drop area, the inspector properly displays the properties/layout/code of the node.

I have tried creating a new `Scene` from scratch which temporarily solves the issue, but is recreated when adding `MenuItem`s or other `Nodes` which are contained in toggleable menus(not visible on the drag and drop screen, only visible in the preview).

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Are you trying to report a perceived bug in SceneBuilder here?

Comment: If you believe you found a bug in _Scene Builder_, please report it over at the [project's GitHub repository](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/issues). Note you're likely going to have to be much more specific. Describe a step-by-step process that reproduces the problem.